# Overriding solution configuration when using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build a solution with custom configuration "Staging" using MSBuild command parameter /p:Configuration=Staging, but I always getting the current configuration from solution properties and the parameter is ignored.

When I set the first project to Release and pass /p:Configuration=Staging, I still getting Release instead of Staging.

I'm using VS2017.[image]

I print the message using

```
<Target Name="temp" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Message Text="Custom message Current configuration: $(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
```

And I got the message `Custom message Current configuration: Release`

When I change the Configuration to Debug from solution property pages and build using MSBuild /p:Configuration=Staging, I got `Custom message Current configuration: Debug`

How can I override solution configuration when using MSBuild?

**Update:**

Here is the solution configuration

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can (well, apart from modifying the text in the .sln file before building). But the canonical way of doing this is adding a solution configuration named Staging and set the individual project configurations as you want them then build that using msbuild. Or else build projects seperately using msbuild.

Comment: I already have a configuration named "Staging" and I'm using MSBuild but the configuration parameter I passed to MSBuild is ignored and it using the default configuration on solution. I want to do that before I could use TFS Build service to deploy my solution.

Comment: Do you have a *Solution* configuration named Staging? That is not the same as a *Project* configuration.

Comment: What is the different between Solution and Project Configuration?

Comment: Solution configuration is for configuring which set of project configurations you are using. Right-click solution, select 'Configuration Manager'. There you have to choose 'Staging' for 'Active solution configuration' (*not* 'All Configurations' as in your screenshot), then in the table 'Project contexts' for the projects select Staging for 'Configuration' (== 'Project Configuration').